# What does "sballati" mean?

Tags: word-meaning, translation, english-comparison

In conversation with Italian (specifically Sicilian) friends, a word has come up which we are struggling to reach a shared understanding of.

The Italian word is *"sballati"* and, when fed through Google Translate, it comes back as "How High" which is confusing to me as a mainly English speaker.

They say it is used when someone drinks, gambles, takes drugs, etc. to excess, so to me it seems to mean something like *vice*; but maybe someone can translate into English to clarify its meaning so that I do not use it inappropriately?

Comment: It looks like it is related to the verb sballare
Just a guess ... "rubbish!"
http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sballato

Comment: @Jim'sMum Thanks for commenting but we think not - it seems to be used when someone drinks, gambles, takes drugs, etc to excess

Comment: I agree with egreg: if you are asking for an *English* word, this is not the right site, even if you explain it by means of an Italian word.

Comment: @PolyGeo, if you rephrase your question we might try to save it; otherwise you might try to propose it [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/). However, the word you might be looking for could be _kick_ (the sharp stimulant effect of alcohol or a drug or a thrill of pleasurable, often reckless excitement).

Comment: @randomatlabuser etc I've edited my question to try and keep it on topic.  Looking around I could not see that it was overly different in structure to an earlier question: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/what-does-idroscalo-mean  In any event when we were struggling for words to share its meaning the English recklessness came up so if you provide kick as an answer I will be happy to accept it.

Comment: I would be curious to know what it means, given that my guess is wrong.

Comment: I don't agree that it's off-topic. The person is asking for a clarification over an Italian jargon word, and aims at understanding its meaning so it's perfectly ok. @randomatlabuser's answer is perfect.

Comment: @martina I retracted my close vote after seeing the edit.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The noun *sballo* can have different usages. It can mean something that is able to provide "*a thrill of pleasurable, often reckless excitement*"; it can also mean "*the sharp stimulant effect of alcohol or a drug*". In these cases the word you might be looking for could be "*kick*", or even "*trip*".

The adjective "*sballato*" can mean something that is absurd, illogical, nonsensical; or it can mean a person that is under the effects of alcohol or heavy drugs; it is also used for people who live a reckless, highly irregular, almost insane life.

Typically, a person who is "sballata" could be someone who has just spent the night in a disco, perhaps drinking too much or taking drugs and dancing uninterruptedly until sunrise, or just having extreme fun, probably more than the body can - or should - actually take.

Finally, "*sbàllati*" is the imperative mood of the verb "*sballare*", and it is an invitation to have wild and reckless fun.

Answer (score 2):

> In conversation with Italian .. a word has come up which we are
>   struggling to reach a shared understanding of...The Italian word is
>   "sballati"... maybe someone can translate into English to clarify its
>   meaning so that I do not use it inappropriately?

"sballato" is the past participle of the verb "sballare" which has the root 'balla'  which means 'a stupid, exaggerated statement': fib, bunkum, baloney

Therefore, if it is used in relation to things like 'price', 'extimate' etc. it means just 'exaggerated', 'out of proportions'; in relation to 'result', 'calculation' etc. it means 'wrong'; in relation to a mechanical device such as 'motore', 'contatore' it means 'out of order', 'busted'.

When it is used with relation to people its root is:

- 1)'sballare' as an intransitive verb that means 'to go wrong/bust', 'to go beyond the acceptable limit'. "è uno sballato" means he is 'nuts', 'a twit'.
- 2) 'sballo': "Nel gergo dei drogati, il particolare e temporaneo effetto di eccitazione e di benessere psicologici e fisici provocato dall’assunzione di droga". Therefore 'sballato' means 'drug-addict': 'quel bar è un covo di sballati", "è entrata in un giro di sballati"